# Avoid copy converting std::vector<std::atomic<T>> to std::vector<T>

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

Assuming I have finished multi-threaded sections, I want to convert my `std::vector<std::atomic<T>>` to a `std::vector<T>`. I can not find a way to do this without a copy. Is a simple `static_cast` safe?

EDIT: Is `reinterpret_cast` safe?

Comment: Performing a static cast  creates a copy. And the compiler won't allow it.

Comment: "Is reinterpret_cast safe?" <-- the answer to this question is almost nearly completely always, "no".

Comment: The atomic types are not required to have the same layout as their underlying types.

Comment: @KerrekSB Would it change much if they were?... Is casting `std::vector<StructA>` to `std::vector<StructB>` safe even if they both were a structure of one integer?

Comment: Though the atomic specializations for integral types do have standard layout, trivial default constructors, and trivial destructors. I don't think you could cast a std::vector<A> to a std::vector<B> legally, but maybe you could have a std::vector of a union of A and B (as long as A and B have standard layout)?

Comment: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0019r1.html permits views of non-atomic values atomically, which looks like what you want.

Comment: @Yakk, yes, that seems to be it. I guess I'll be copying data for a few years until this is implemented.